# NullPointerException with android on loaders/asynctaskloader

Tags: android, android-asynctask, loader

Making a twitter android app. Trying to make the OAuth work. I'm getting a nullpointerexception when trying to initialize the consumer.

Here's my main activity plus the asynctaskloader class:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks{

final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private OAuthConsumer consumer;
private OAuthProvider provider;
private String token;
private String secret;
private getCommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumerLoader;

Activity context;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sign_in();
        }
    });     
}


public void sign_in()
{
    try {

        Log.i(TAG, "test");

        this.consumer = (OAuthConsumer) getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this); //here's the error

        Log.i(TAG, "test2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider",e);
    }       
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public android.support.v4.content.Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) {
    consumerLoader = new getCommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(context);
    return consumerLoader;
}


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader arg0,
        Object arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}





class getCommonsHttpOAuthConsumer extends AsyncTaskLoader<OAuthConsumer>{

public getCommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public OAuthConsumer loadInBackground() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
}

}
```

Here's my logcat:

```
04-16 13:03:54.976: I/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476): test
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476): Error     creating consumer / provider
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.support.v4.content.Loader.<init>(Loader.java:91)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.<init>(AsyncTaskLoader.java:92)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at com.example.twittertestnewapi.getCommonsHttpOAuthConsumer.<init>(MainActivity.java:115)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity.onCreateLoader(MainActivity.java:87)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:490)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:499)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:553)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity.sign_in(MainActivity.java:68)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-16 13:03:54.986: E/com.example.twittertestnewapi.MainActivity(22476):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't initialize the `context` variable that you use with the `Loader`. In the `onCreate()` method add:

```
context = this;
```

Comment: Luksprog is right, but why are you holding a reference to the context like this? Just use GetBaseContext() or getApplicationContext() (that's all it uses under the hood anyways)

Comment: @natez0r Or he could simply use `this` as it points to the current `Activity`.

Comment: @natez0r I don't know what I'm doing, i'm pretty noob. Why do you think i should use them instead?

Comment: @Jello The activity that you are running in is a context and also provides methods to access the base/application context if need be. It's redundant to store a reference to yourself. Also, it's definitely preferable to avoid storing references to Activity context objects when possible because it's a common source of memory leaks (if you keep a reference to an activity in some other object, and that activity is killed, it's memory may not be reclaimable). In this case, you should be OK as long as it wasn't a static reference but it's best to avoid it.